# SQL Server transaction log, dbcc not really useful, ldf file not accessible, don't want to install 3rd party software

Tags: sql-server, logging, transactions

I'm trying to track down why a db query got screwed in SQL Server (just the one time).

`dbcc log(mydb,2)` is not filterable by date(?). And the ldf file I can't access directly without going through 2 layers of bureaucracy

Any suggestions? Other than installing some 3rd party proprietary log file viewer.

Comment: What do you mean by "query got screwed"? Could you describe the problem more exactly?

Comment: not really, thats what I am trying to track down. I know when stored proc was called, from my webserver log, now trying to track it down on db logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may apply ORDER BY, WHERE et al usual SQL (is not it filtering language?) to

> SELECT *  FROM fn_dblog(null,null)

It is undocumented (not in BOL) feature but google gives a plethora of articles on it and its use