# How can I find information about updating or inserting a sql table row in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-insert, ldf

I am looking for information about my table history,
I have to know the time that specific row was inserted
is there someway to know it?
thanks.

Comment: You may find these answers useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767054, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675338

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Triggers**

> A `Datetime column` in that table and an `After Insert,Update Trigger`
>   which updates that column to `GETDATE()`.
>
> This will only give you the details about the very last
>   change(update/Insert).

**CDC**

> Change Data Capture (CDC) was introduced in SQL Server 2008. Change
>   Data Capture records INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs applied to SQL
>   Server tables, and makes a record available of what changed, where,
>   and when, in simple relational ‘change tables’.
>
> These "Change Tables" contain columns that reflect the column
>   structure of the source table you have chosen to track, along with the
>   metadata needed to understand the changes that have been made.
>
> **[Read here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-%28cdc%29-in-sql-server-2008/) more about CDC**
>
> *Also it is only supported in Datacenter & Enterprise edition.*